# MongoDB Filter to check if binary field is not empty

Tags: c#, database, mongodb

I have long binary blob (a stored PNG actually with miniature) in MongoDB. I need a filter that will return all slugs with non-empty blob.

I tried something like this:

```
var f = Builders<Common.Json.Database.Picture>.Filter.Where(pic => pic.ContentMini.Length > 0 && pic.ContentFull.Length > 0);
var p = Builders<Common.Json.Database.Picture>.Projection.Include(x => x.Slug);
var s = Builders<Common.Json.Database.Picture>.Sort.Ascending(x => x.Slug);

return Collections.Pictures.Find(f)
                            .Project<Common.Json.Database.Picture>(p)
                            .Sort(s)
                            .ToList()
                            .Select(x => x.Slug);
```

But this returns empty set. If I change `Filter` to `Filter.Empty` I am recieving all slugs in my collection.

The collection definition is below:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Picture
{
    [BsonId]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [NonSerialized]
    public ObjectId InternalId;

    [BsonElement("slug")]
    [JsonProperty("slug")]
    public string Slug;

    [BsonElement("author")]
    [JsonProperty("author")]
    public Common.Author Author;

    [BsonElement("owner")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    [JsonProperty("owner")]
    public Guid OwningUserOrGroup;

    [BsonElement("keywords")]
    [JsonProperty("keywords")]
    public List<string> Keywords = new List<string>();

    [BsonElement("last_updated")]
    [JsonProperty("last_updated")]
    public DateTime LastUpdated;

    [BsonElement("is_approved")]
    [JsonProperty("is_approved")]
    public bool IsApproved;

    [BsonElement("is_obsolete")]
    [JsonProperty("is_obsolete")]
    public bool IsObsolete;

    [BsonElement("content_mini")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Binary)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public byte[] ContentMini;

    [BsonElement("content_full")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Binary)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public byte[] ContentFull;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty `byte` array gets stored in MongoDB as `"content_mini" : BinData(0,"")` so you can simply use `$ne` to build your query in Mongo shell

```
db.pictures.find( {"content_mini": { $ne: new BinData(0,"") } } )
```

To build that query in C# you need `Builders` generic type and `Ne` method. To filter out all empty arrays and `null` values you can use below code:

```
var filter = Builders<Picture>.Filter.Ne(f => f.ContentMini, new byte[] { });
var filter2 = Builders<Picture>.Filter.Ne(f => f.ContentMini, null);
var result = Col.Find(filter & filter2).ToList();
```

You shouldn't use `Filter.Empty` because it actaully represents empty query, just like `db.col.find({})` in Mongo shell